# Open files and work faster with the words (In C)

Tags: c, list, hash

Hi I am working on a function that receives a file (.txt) pointer, a first struct (could be a list or a hash's table) and a second struct (could be list or a hash's table) and a function  which receive 2 structures and store the file words on one of them. I made a `word_struct` function because I want to have got only function to open a dictionary and store the words in a hash table, and open other text file, and save only the words which isn't in the dictionary in a list. So just I need to change the `strct_f` function to open each file type. But should be there a faster way to do that, because it takes a few seconds to work (maybe because the text file with the dictionary has got 700.000 words).
It is important to say, that this method avoids storing a big array for the dictionary, and just work with each word. So I haven`t spend a lot of memory at the same time.

Is it a complex and dirty code? and is there other way to do this? Thanks you so much!

```
void *word_struct(FILE *fptr, void *strct, void *strct2, strct_f strct_f) {
    int empty_file = 0, i = 0;
    char a;            
    char *temp = malloc(sizeof(char) * BUFFER);
    while (empty_file != 1) {
        if ((a = fgetc(fptr)) == EOF) {
            empty_file = 1;
            if (i != 0) {
                temp[i] = '\0';
                strct_f(strct, strct2, temp);
            }
            free(temp);
        } else
        if ((a >= 97 && a <= 122) || (a >= 65 && a <= 90)) {
            temp[i] = (char)tolower(a);
            i += 1;
        } else {
            if (i != 0) {
                temp[i] = '\0';
                strct_f(strct, strct2, temp);
                free(temp);
                temp = malloc(sizeof(char) * BUFFER);
                i = 0;  
            }
        }
    }
    return strct;
}
```

Comment: There might be a performance hit on the `malloc()` and `free()` called within the loop. It seems to be for every word.

Comment: I don't see any good reason for repeated malloc/free in this code or really for any dynamic memory management at all. Better to fix the source files so everything is already lowercase. You might also structure them to be easier to read in chunks rather than one character at a time.

Comment: Lkx8888, Also, Save the 257 different responses of `fgetc(fptr)` in an `int`.

Comment: If these are actual words from real sentences, just use a fixed array and check for overflow. It also depends on what `strct_f()` is doing with each word, which you don't show. Does it open a file for append and close it for every word? Or does it open the file once, write sequentially, and close it once.

Comment: @WeatherVane no, this function is  called in other which recibe an array (file name and path) and close it at the end.

Comment: @Dmitry why? sorry  i want every feedback, because i am learning

Comment: @RetiredNinja because i need memory to work with each word. I want to avoid alloc the dictionary in a big memory space. So i create a litle space to save a word, and then i will need it to save other word

Comment: @Lkx8888 can you please change your code to use `int a;` instead of `char a;`,  fgetc signature is `int fgetc(FILE *stream)`, if it is not EOF, THEN you can treat it as a char, until then you treat it as an int. As for readability, there are no comments, you are using integer literals for characters when you could just use 'a' instead of 97 and 'z' instead of 122, the variable name `empty_file` is misleading and not obvious,  the variable name `temp` is misleading and not obvious especially when you get to `if (i != 0) { temp[i] = '\0';` which is as obfuscated as it can get, and more.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica i try to learn best ways to code, and all comments are great!

Comment: @Dmitry oh i understand, thanks you for take the time to  answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues in your code:

- using opaque `void *` arguments and return value is unsafe: this defeats the compiler type checking features.
- `strct_f strct_f` is ugly: you shadow the name of the type with the variable name. Use `strct_f fun` instead.
- `a` must be defined as an `int` to test `EOF` properly and call `tolower()` with an argument in the proper range. It is more idiomatic to use the name `c` for this variable.
- you always allocate `BUFFER` bytes for all words. This is wasteful and may cause the program to run slower
- you do not test for buffer overflow when storing the next character into the `temp` array, invoking undefined behavior on bogus dictionaries.
- the last `temp` buffer is not freed, causing a memory leak.
- hard coding ASCII values for the letters is non portable, hard to read and less efficient than using `isalpha(c)`
- the words in the dictionary might legitimately contain dashes and some other non alpha bytes.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void *word_struct(FILE *fp, void *p1, void *p2, strct_f fun) {
    char buf[BUFFER];
    size_t i = 0;

    for (;;) {
        int c = getc(fp);
        if (isalpha(c)) {
            if (i < sizeof(buf) - 1) {
                buf[i++] = (char)tolower(c);
            }
        } else {
            if (i > 0) {
                buf[i] = '\0';
                fun(p1, p2, strdup(buf));
                i = 0;  
            }
            if (c == EOF)
                break;
        }
    }
    return p1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much! i am going to try it!

Comment: *you always allocate `BUFFER` bytes for all words. This is wasteful and may cause the program to run slower*  IMO it's more likely to make the program run **faster** - at least as long as no word causes a buffer overflow.  There will be almost no heap fragmentation if the same size buffer is used all the time.  If you're going to do that, though, `char temp[ BUFFER ];` is probably even better - no real dynamic allocation at all, although that does require `BUFFER` to be more limited in size.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: it really depends on how large `BUFFER` is and how heap allocation works.  I wrote *may cause the program to run slower*, this is not an absolute statement, just a possibility. In my own experience with spelling benchmarks, reducing the total memory footprint of the dictionary tends to improve cache efficiency.  Arena fragmentation is not an issue as the dictionary is allocated in a streak and does not change over time. Allocating a large buffer for all words and storing offsets or pointers in the hash table is probably a better approach.